# How to create user with secured password field

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I have a `/users` endpoint and want to secure the user's password. So I want to prevent updating password and retrieving it by get request, also I need some way to encrypt password before it will be stored. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found by myself. Event hooks is that I looking for. http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks